# How to disable Formtastic classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

Whenever i use Formtastic form helpers, it adds this as the `class` attribute to the form:

```
<form class="formtastic #{class_name}"></form>
```

That ends up causing me issues, How to disable those default classes? I already use:

`:html{ :class => 'foo' }`

but that just gets appended.

Answer (score 0):

Any classes you provide will get appended to the default ones provided by Formtastic. Your best option is to redefine the default classes in a separate CSS file which you'll include in the layout after the default Formtastic stylesheet.